# Exportar Imagem de Tabela HTML para EXCEL ou PDF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela em HTML, na última coluna é exibido uma imagem (JPEG, PNG). É possível exportar essa tabela para EXCEL ou PDF com a imagem?
Usei o DataTables para fazer um teste, porém, a imagem não é exportada junto com a tabela.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Export DataTable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
    
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:80%; margin: 10px auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Imagem</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td><img src="https://www.supercarros.cc/uploads/default/files/unidade/3/foz_img_1.jpg" height="100px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td><img src="http://www.imagenswiki.com/Uploads/imagenswiki.com/ImagensGrandes/imagens-motos-honda.jpg" height="100px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td><img src="http://fotos.jornaldocarro.estadao.com.br/uploads/2017/09/30172748/Hennessey-Venom_GT-2011-1280-05-1160x709.jpg" height="100px"></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
       lengthChange: false,
       buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf']
      } );

      table.buttons().container()
      .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
     } );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu utilizo um plugin para facilitar, deixei o exemplo para download no link abaixo [Download dos arquivos](http://programano.marsites.com.br/download/programacao/excelexport/jquery-excel-export.zip) [Link do exemplo](http://programano.marsites.com.br/download/programacao/excelexport/index.html)

Comment: http://www.randrade.net/2016/05/26/convertendo-tabelas-html-em-arquivos-excel-no-front-end/#disqus_thread
Talvez este link te auxilie.